# Using batch size with TensorFlow Validation Monitor

Tags: tensorflow, out-of-memory, deep-learning, gpu, conv-neural-network

I'm using `tf.contrib.learn.Estimator` to train a CNN having 20+ layers. I'm using GTX 1080 (8 GB) for training. My dataset is not so large but my GPU runs out of memory with a batch size greater than 32. So I'm using a batch size of 16 for training and Evaluating the classifier (GPU runs out of memory while evaluation as well if a batch_size is not specified).

```
  # Configure the accuracy metric for evaluation
  metrics = {
      "accuracy":
          learn.MetricSpec(
              metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
  }

  # Evaluate the model and print results
  eval_results = classifier.evaluate(
      x=X_test, y=y_test, metrics=metrics, batch_size=16)
```

Now the problem is that after every 100 steps, I only get training loss printed on screen. I want to print validation loss and accuracy as well, So I'm using a `ValidationMonitor`

```
 validation_monitor = tf.contrib.learn.monitors.ValidationMonitor(
      X_test,
      y_test,
      every_n_steps=50)
  # Train the model
  classifier.fit(
      x=X_train,
      y=y_train,
      batch_size=8,
      steps=20000,
      monitors=[validation_monitor]
```

**ActualProblem:** My code crashes (Out of Memory) when I use `ValidationMonitor`, I think the problem might be solved if I could specify a batch size here as well and I can't figure out how to do that. I want `ValidationMonitor` to evaluate my validation data in batches, like I do it manually after training using `classifier.evaluate`, is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ValidationMonitor's constructor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.1/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/monitors.py#L564) accepts a `batch_size` arg that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `config=tf.contrib.learn.RunConfig( save_checkpoints_secs=save_checkpoints_secs)` in your model definition. The save_checkpoints_secs can be changed to save_checkpoints_steps, but not both.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see 'Help' at the top right of the answer window to see how to format code.